# fviz_cluster, change color of pt to reflect key

Tags: r

Hi suppose I have this cluster plot below.

```
data("iris")
head(iris)
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 10)
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm")
```

[image]

however for each point I want to change the color to reflect the 3 species.

```
# change the color points to relect the 3 species
unique ( iris$Species)
```

However it does not work when I tried something like, `fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], ellipse.type = "norm", col= iris$Species)` Ultimately what I want is to have each of the point colored by species and perhaps just make the elliptical into clear or something.  Is this is possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is bit old. However, the following might be helpful for automatic colour assignment:

```
+ scale_color_brewer(type='div', palette=2)    OR
+ scale_color_brewer(type='qual')              OR
+ scale_color_brewer(type='seq', palette='Reds') # to show different colours for clusters
```

And these could be useful for manual colour manipulations:

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "orange", "red")) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "orange", "red"))
```

For further information, you may refer to the following:

http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/scale_color_brewer.html

http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=diverging&scheme=RdGy&n=3